# Cannot re-enable boostrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a change event on an input field. The code below is responsible for popping up a tooltip when the user input is invalid.

```
if (termInput > maxTerm) {
            $('#term').tooltip('enable');
            $('#term').tooltip({'title':'Term has been adjusted to maximum allowed'});
            $('#term').tooltip('show');
            $("#term").val(maxTerm);

            // Hide tooltip after a while
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#term').tooltip('disable');
            }, 3000);
        }
```

The tooltip doesn't appear when the code `$('#term').tooltip('enable');` is present. If it matters, I'm disabling the tooltip after a timeout so that it doesn't keep popping up whenever the user hovers on the input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues here. 
First start by setting the trigger of the tooltip to manual. This way it doesnt popup on hover. No need to work with enabled / disabled.

To change the title, change the attribute 'data-original-title'.

Please check my snippet and verify if it works like you expect.

```js
$('#example').tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
})

$('#example').keyup(function(){

  if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            $('#example').attr('data-original-title', 'Term has been adjusted to maximum allowed').tooltip('show');
            
            // Hide tooltip after a while
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#example').tooltip('hide');
            }, 3000);
        }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<input type="number" id="example" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```